# Analytics' Enhanced Link attribution not working for simple non-JS links

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm adding Google Analytics (`analytics.js`) to my site, but Enhanced Link attribution is not working even on the simplest cases.

Checklist:

- I activated "Enhanced Link Attribution" on the admin page of the property;
- Tracking code is present on all pages of the system (just before `</head>`), including `linkid.js`:

  ```
  <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'U-ANALYTICS-ID', 'auto');
      ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
  ```
- My links are regular ones, no JS involved, with different IDs:

  ```
      <a id="link1" href="/destination">Link 1</a>
      <a id="link2" href="/destination">Link 2</a>
  ```
- Using Firebug I can see that both `analytics.js` and `linkid.js` are loaded, and after going to `/destination`, a `pageview` event is sent with the correct `linkid` parameter, according to the clicked link.

I really don't know what's wrong. The result is that In-page Analytics shows the same percentage for both links, with a range of click counts.

Any help is appreciated.